# ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR при переходе по https

Tags: node.js, nginx, apache

При переходе на сайте https://my_url:3000 выбивает ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR, ниже прикреплю код из конфига nginx - default.

```
server {
     listen 3000;
     listen 443 ssl;
     server_name my_url;
     ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my_url/fullchain.pem;
     ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my_url/privkey.pem;
     location / {
         proxy_pass https://my_url:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
     }
}
```

В чём проблема?

Comment: Через `proxy_pass https://my_url:3000;` у Вас будут циклические запросы на сам же сервер. Это, вероятно, вызовет ошибку и сервер не будет работать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В строке

```
listen 3000;
```

Добавьте `ssl`, как и на следующей строке в вопросе, что бы на порту 3000 слушался не HTTP, а HTTPS.

```
listen 3000 ssl;
```

Comment: Заработало :) 
А ещё вопрос, если можно.
Я запускаю nginx на 3000 порте, а сервер ноды на 3001.
Что мне изменить в конфиге, чтобы запросы шли на nginx, а оттуда уже на сервер node.js (надеюсь выразился правильно и понятно)

Comment: а то вылетает "502 Bad Gateway".
Как я понимаю, nginx получил запрос от клиента, но не смог его отправить на node.js

Comment: Проблему решил, ошибка была в https://my_url:3000, изменил на http://my_url:5000
И поменял порт прослушки на сервере node.js на 5000

Спасибо!